# "The high OS version validation detected" error during Windows App Certification Kit validation

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-store

Getting the following test failure while running `Windows App Certification Kit 10.0`:

```
Platform version launch

Error Found: The high OS version validation detected the following errors:

Cannot launch App
The app <apppackagename> failed platform version launch test.

Impact if not fixed: The app should not use version information to provide functionality that is specific to the OS.

How to fix: Please use recommended methods to check for available functionality in the OS. See the link below for more information.
```

Any feedback on how to resolve that issue appreciated.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: I ignored it at that time and submitted app to the store. It successfully went through submission process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your Windows App Certification Kit to the latest version and then update the "Target version" inside the solution's properties to the latest windows build version (2004).
Now Create app package again and you will be OK :)